# Tracert command request timed out windows 10

Tags: windows, cmd, traceroute

```
C:\Windows\system32>tracert google.com

Tracing route to google.com [142.250.194.14]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  XXXXXXXXXXX
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  XXXXXXXXXXX
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  XXXXXXXXXXX
  4     3 ms     2 ms     2 ms  static.ill.XXXXXXXXXXXXX/24.XXXX.in [XXXXXXXX]
  5     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     6 ms    10 ms     6 ms  142.250.160.182
  8    17 ms    14 ms     *     142.251.77.185
  9     8 ms     8 ms     7 ms  142.251.52.199
 10     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 11     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 12     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 13     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 14     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 15     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 16     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 17     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 18     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 19     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 20     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 21     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 22     *        *        *     Request timed out.
 23     *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

I did turn my firewall off but the result was only the same. I changed my ISP (used 3 different companies), but the result is exactly the same. After 4 hops, 2 timeouts, and after the 9th request, all timeouts until 30. I run cmd under administrative mode. I'm using windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that the 10th hop is dropping ICMP packets and they are not being passed on. If the first 9 show response times then it's not you, and not likely to be your ISP either unless they have many routers involved in the transport.

ICMP (the protocol used by traceroute) is of the lowest priority and, when higher priority traffic is ongoing, the router may be configured to simply drop ICMP packets. There is also the possibility that the ISP drops all ICMP packets as a matter of security since many DOS (Denial of Service) attacks are based on probing done with ICMP packets.

Maybe a duplicate? [tracert command returns timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356782/tracert-command-returns-timed-out)