# I connect to my Azure VPN successfully. I'm having problems RDPing into my VM after allowing a firewall rule IP address issued by the VPN

Tags: azure, azure-vpn

I've setup an Azure P2S VPN successfully and my client is able to connect to a local static IP address, but I'm having problems RDPing into my VM after allowing a firewall rule port 3389 for specific IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce same in my environment setup Azure P2S VPN and connected to RDP successfully.***

Once your vpn is created verify ip allocation from VPN address pool is active.  Open command prompt run **ipconfig/all** as below.

[image]

check whether you add inbound port rule as below.

[image]

Now, I can able to connect RDP connection successfully as below.

[image][image]

If you are issue still persists, check my answer of same related issue [Azure: VM in another spoke virtual network cannot be accessed via RDP - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738270/azure-vm-in-another-spoke-virtual-network-cannot-be-accessed-via-rdp/73744428#73744428)

***Reference:***

[Step-By-Step: Creating an Azure Point-to-Site VPN (microsoft.com)](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-creating-an-azure-point-to-site-vpn/ba-p/326264) by *Dishan Francis*